# Call member function from interrupt in STM32

Tags: stm32, c, arm, c++, keil

I have created a new STM32 project using cube. I have changed `main.c` to `main.cpp` and enabled `--cpp` in the compiler. If something complains I add extern c so c++ can see it.

I have c++ code running "fine". However now that I started using interrupts I'm experiencing some problems.

I am using UART and HAL. I have defined `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` as `extern "C" void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)`. When there is a new character in UART the interrupt is executed and the function called correctly. As far as I understand my code is running in c++ in the callback and should be able to access my objects methods.

I want to execute `m.onReceiveCharacter()` from the callback where `m` for now is a global variable in the `main.cpp` file. The object has the method I try to call. I add that line to the interrupt and I can see with the debugger that the function is called and I can go trough it correctly.

However what happens is that sometimes (I still haven't found the logic) some of the members of `m` change for no apparent reason. For example I have a private member `UART_HandleTypeDef* huart` that is pointed to the right huart at the beggining when I initialize and after an interrupt (before even the `m.onReceiveCharacter()` is executed) changes "randomly" to another address.

Usually, if I have a function in the main loop doing some operations on `m` and the interrupt comes then suddenly the value of `huart` is changed. The value of `huart` is never changed in any way in the code and this happens before the interrupt code inside the function is called (but the callback function already entered to). I have seen similar issues with other variables that are also not to be changed.

Any ideas?

**Summary:** Some of the members of my object change "randomly" to new values when an interrupt comes. What are the possible causes? I am using STM32F030R8, with a project generated by Cube, in Keil compiler version 5.

Comment: Impossible to debug without the code. Though if you have trace possibilities in your debugger, simply set a write breakpoint on the data and see who's the culprit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can other functions of `m` be interrupted by `m.onReceiveCharacter()`?

Comment: Generally you should try to do as little in an ISR as possible.  Could you perhaps set a flag or buffer the character and then deal with it in something called from the main loop?

Answer (score 2):

After creating a very simple project and seeing it work I went back to the code. Going slowly with the debugger I found some functions after each the values went random. The functions were doing nothing to those values! And it happened **right after entering in them, without executing any code**. Then it came to me, stack overflow! I doubled the stack and now all the problems are gone.